# Increment UILabel from UserDefaults value - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am creating a counter and would like to be able to increment by 1 on every button press, which updates my UILabel and saves to UserDefaults. I am able to save and retrieve the values perfectly fine, but when I press the button again, the number goes back to one.

Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let save = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "points1") as? String
        {
            teamOnePoint.text = save
            print(save)
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func teamOneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        pointScore1 += 1
        teamOnePoint.text = "\(pointScore1)"
        UserDefaults.standard.set(teamOnePoint.text, forKey: "points1")

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set `pointScore1` to the value retrieved from `UserDefaults`.

Start by retrieving and storing the `Int` value, not a `String`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pointScore1 = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "points1")
    teamOnePoint.text = "\(pointScore1)"
}

@IBAction func teamOneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    pointScore1 += 1
    teamOnePoint.text = "\(pointScore1)"
    UserDefaults.standard.set(pointScore1, forKey: "points1")
}
```

Note that after a fresh install of the app, the initial value will be `0`. Deal with that as desired.

Answer (score -2):

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let save = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "points1") as? String
    {
         print(save)
    }
}

@IBAction func btnIncrTap(_ sender: Any)
{
    pointScore1 += 1
    UserDefaults.standard.set(pointScore1, forKey: "points1")
    print(String(describing: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "points1")))
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix anything. And please don't post code-only answers. A good answer explains what was wrong and how the answer fixes the issue.